# Active choices reactive reference parameter as formatted html in jenkins pipeline with default value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm trying to create Active choice HTML parameter with default value in jenkins pipeline and I can't find a problem.

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
            omitValueField: true,
            referencedParameters: '',
            description: 'Test', 
            name: 'TEST', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-46431548642', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get any info\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        '''
                        return "<input name=\\"value\\" value=\\"Test\\" class=\\"setting-input\\" type=\\"text\\">" 
                        '''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])
```

It's working fine when I use:

```
return "<input name=\\"value\\" value=\\"\\" class=\\"setting-input\\" type=\\"text\\">"
```

without a value, but I got empty field then.
Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly having the problem as you, cannot find a way to assign default value to formatted html <input>, thought it's a common use case but did not see the doc mentioning how to set a default value. Honestly it's frustrating to see not much resources online after hours of googling.

Comment: Well actually I found this doc page, not sure if it's up to date - https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=81068371   it did not solve my problem since I'm using `DynamicReferenceParameter` instead, but it might help your case dealing with choice.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing entry for  `referencedParameters: ''`

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
            omitValueField: true,
            referencedParameters: '**ADD value here**',
            description: 'Test', 
            name: 'TEST', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-46431548642', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get any info\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        '''
                        return "<input name=\\"value\\" value=\\"Test\\" class=\\"setting-input\\" type=\\"text\\">" 
                        '''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).